# codeigniter registration tab not displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, tabs

I am using codeigniter with foundation as my front end, on my index view I have a tab with the login and registration forms on, my login form tab displays but when I click on the sign up tab it does not display. when I view the page source the registration view has been loaded correctly into my main view it just does not display.

authentication.php (default view that is loaded)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="authentication_tab">
  <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Login</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2" >Sign Up</a></li>

</ul>
<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="authentication_tab">
  <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
  <?php $this->load->view('authentication/login');?>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel " id="panel2">
  <?php $this->load->view('authentication/reg');?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php $this->load->view('templates/footer');?>
```

login form

```
<?php $attributes= array('id'=>'login_form','class'=>'form_horizontal');?>


<?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')):?>

<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');?>

<?php endif;?>


<?php echo form_open('Authentication/login_check',$attributes);?>


 <div class="medium-12 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Email'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'email',
'placeholder'=>'Email'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>

<div class="medium-12 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Password'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'password',
'placeholder'=>'Password'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>

<?php

$data = array(

'class'=>'button large-12',
'name'=>'register',
'id'=>'register',
'value'=>'Register'


);?>
<?php echo form_submit($data);?>
</div>   

<?echo form_close();?>
```

registration form

```
<?php $attributes= array('id'=>'registration_form','class'=>'form_horizontal');?>


<?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')):?>

<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors');?>

<?php endif;?>


<?php echo form_open('Authentication/registration_check',$attributes);?>


 <div class="medium-6 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('First Name'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'id'=>'fname',
'name'=>'fname',
'placeholder'=>'First Name'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>

 <div class="medium-6 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Last Name'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'lname',
'placeholder'=>'Last Name'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>

 <div class="medium-6 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Email'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'email',
'placeholder'=>'Email'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>
 <div class="medium-6 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Confirm Email'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'cemail',
'placeholder'=>'Confirm Email'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>
 <div class="medium-6 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Password'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'password',
'placeholder'=>'Password'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>
 <div class="medium-6 columns">    
<?php 
echo form_label('Confirm Password'); 
$data = array(

'class'=>'form-control',
'name'=>'cpassword',
'placeholder'=>'Confirm Password'


);

echo form_input($data);
?>
</div>

 <div class="medium-4 columns">
<?php echo "<select name='day' id='day'><option value='default'>day</option>";
for($i=1; $i<32; $i++){
    echo "<option value='$i'".($i==$_POST["day"] ? " selected" : null).">$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";?>
    </div>
<div class="medium-4 columns">
  <?php
echo "<select name='month' id='month'><option value='default'>month</option>";
for($i=1; $i<13; $i++){
    echo "<option value='$i'".($i==$_POST["month"] ? " selected" : null).">$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns">

<?php
echo "<select name='year'id='year'><option value='default' >year</option>";
for($i=1900; $i<2016; $i++){
    echo "<option value='$i'".($i==$_POST["year"] ? " selected" : null).">$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
    </div>



<?php

$data = array(

'class'=>'button large-12',
'name'=>'register',
'id'=>'register',
'value'=>'Register'


);?>
<?php echo form_submit($data);?>
</div>   

<?echo form_close();?>
```

authentication.css

```
body{
     background-color:#f2f2f0;

 }
/* registration and login form tab design*/
 .tabs {
    width:400px;

    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    border-top-left-radius:2em;
    border-top-right-radius:2em;
}
.tabs,.tabs-content {
    border-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.tabs a{
    width:199px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2199e8;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    text-align:center;

}

 .tabs-title > a:focus, .tabs-title > a[aria-selected='true'] {
 background: white; 
 color:#147cc0;
 border-top-right-radius:2em;
 border-top-left-radius:2em;

 }
.tabs-title > a:hover {

      border-top-right-radius:2em;
      border-top-left-radius:2em;
      color:#147cc0;
}



.tabs-content {
           width:400px;
           background-color:#fff;
        border-bottom-left-radius:2em;
        border-bottom-right-radius:2em;
}

.row {

position:absolute;
top:30%;
left:40%;
margin-top:-50px; /* this is half the height of your div*/  
margin-left:-100px; /*this is half of width of your div*/
 }

.button {
border-radius:5px;
font-weight: bold;
}

/* End of registration and login form tab design*/


/* registration form style */

label,#day,#month,#year {
    color: #2199e8;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.form-control {
color:#147cc0;
font-weight:bold;
}



/* End of registration form style */

/* callout style  */

.email_success {
border-radius:20px;    
background-color:#7CFF8A;   
color:white;
width:800px;    
position:absolute;
top:30%;
left:30%;
margin-top:-50px; /* this is half the height of your div*/  
margin-left:-100px; /*this is half of width of your div*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

}

/* End of callout style */
```

Comment: if its already there in your page source, then it won't be a ci issue but a css issue

Comment: okay thanks would it be somthing to do with positioning

Comment: iv added my css code

Comment: if you want to get someone help, make a static html demo page and modify your question to a css issue

Comment: i don't think it can be a css issue because when I had my login form as a standard HTML form rather than what u see above, the registration form displayed I think its a ci issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Please add the below things if not added**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation-flex.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/plugins/foundation.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/plugins/foundation.tabs.js"></script>
```

After reading documentation properly i have found that we need to initialize it as mentioned here http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#initializing

so simply add one more thing i.e.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

and your code will start working.

Comment: this does not work thinks its an older version of foundation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help I found out what the problem was.

at the bottom of my login view I missed the php off of the php tag shown below

```
<?echo form_close();?>
```

changed to this

```
<?php echo form_close();?>
```